# Angular 2 + Phonegap: how can they works together? How to set a basic template and a working apk?

Tags: cordova, angular

i'm new on angular 2 and phonegap. I want to use them together, but i can't figured out how they works together:

- a phonegap basic project has a structure (e.g. the source folder is "www", it has his "package.json" file, etc)
- an angular2 basic project has a different structure (e.g. the source folder is "src", it needs a node_modules folder, it has his "package.json", etc)

I tried to merge them (e.g. for the "package.json" I merged the content of the two package.json, etc). I don't know if the merge is correct, but anyway i don't understand how they works together, because they have different way to test:

- phonegap: i can use the desktop application for run the project, or "phonegap serve" from terminal. I tried to create the apk too, and test it on a real device, but in every of these way, my angular2 section doesn't work (only the basic html)
- angular2: for testing an agular2 project, i have to do "npm start"...if I do it into the phonegap-merge project, the angular section2 works.

So i can't figured out how to make them works together in a apk build.
Few days ago, i experimented with Ionic 2, e when I build an apk with Ionic2, angular2 sections works. So I wonder if phonegap "compile" command does not include some "server" for angular2.
Anyway, i don't want use Ionic2 because it has his own speciale tags

Thanks

Comment: Hey man, I'm looking for do that also, did you find any solution? (without ionic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make project using angular-cli,
You make one cordova project
Then in your angular-cli.json file -> change the path to cordova's www folder.

Then when you do 
ng prod build, your resources would be copied to cordova's www folder.

I wrote one cordova hook for the same,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;



module.exports = function(context) {
    const basePath = context.opts.projectRoot;
    const baseWWW = basePath + '/www';

process.chdir('../bmi-surgical-app');
console.log(`New directory: ${process.cwd()}`);

    execSync("ng build --prod --base-href .",{stdio:[0,1,2]});

    var files = fs.readdirSync(baseWWW);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith('.gz')) {
        fs.unlinkSync(baseWWW + '/' + files[i]);
      }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(baseWWW + '/.gitignore', `# Ignore everything in this directory

*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
`);


};
```

However many better options are available like NativeScript & Ionic 2.

Comment: I tried, but when I run "phonegap build android" I have this error:
Execution failed for task ':mergeArmv7DebugAssets'.

Anyway, when I "change the path to cordova's www folder", and than "ng build --prod --base-href", the cordova's www folder is deleted and recreated. Is it correct? I mean, all the original files in the cordova's ww folder are missing

Comment: @Johannes are u using my hook ?
Yes its correct..
If you are not using my hook, then you need to delete files with .gz in www ...!!

Comment: Yes, i removed the .gz, teh error was on android sdk min ( i have to use cordova crosswalk, i'm on android 4.3 on my test device). Anyway, angular2 doesn't work, i see "loading" on main page, instead of "App works"

Comment: @Johannes : then you can upvote & mark my post as answer :D

Comment: But Angular2 doesn't work, so for now i'm in the same situation of yestarday

Comment: No error, but Angular2 does not work, it's like i open my index.html in the browser of my desktop. I think Angular2 needs some kind of "server" to work, if you want to test a basic angular2 project on a PC, you have to do "npm start" or "ng serve". In a mobile app, it should be automatic and integrated. 
When I build an .apk from an angular2 project with Ionic2, in the generated mobile app Angular2 works properly.
When i build an .apk from this angular2 project with Cordova/Phonegap, in the generated app Angular2 doesn't work.

Comment: no it works & Angular 2 is a client side language.
1. Make sure a valid base href is provided
2. To check errors you can connect android phone & open chrome://inspect, then you can do f12 & Inspect for errors.

Comment: Errores are: file:///styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and the same for the others files generated with "ng build --prod".

Comment: 1. Check wheather this file is there or not in your www folder.  2. Check if its there then what is the path in index.html ....  3. What is the base href you have added ... i have similar kind of setup and angular cli and cordova worked for me

Comment: Ok now it seems to work, my mistake! I did not include the "." in the --base-href command! I had a href="/" intstead of href="./" or simply ".".
Sorry, i thougth Angular needed a kind of server becouse in every examples they speak about the "npm start". Now i know that the "build" command make Angular works standalone.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ionic Framework 2 that was released just yesterday. It uses Cordova though, but Phonegap is distro of Cordova, so you can go for it if it suites you.

Here is documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks, but like a write in the post..i don't want to use Ionic. I'd like to understand how can I make it works without another layer (ionic)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick up `Phonegap` your best bet would be `angular-cli` it uses webpack as well as automated build for dev or production can be configurable and after all you would need to add less js files in your production build